# Visual Studio/devenv: Ensure Preprocessor Macros run when using devenv/CLI

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, preprocessor, devenv

Using Visual Studio 2005, I have been having an issue where devenv behaves differently than the GUI IDE, even when calling VCvarsall.bat and using the /useenv switch to devenv.  Something is getting called that is creating a bunch of files, even when I only run clean on this project (when I use the GUI, I need devenv to behave the same way).  The only thing I can find which might be the cause is the preprocessor macros.  There is no prebuild or prelink event, only a post build event which doesn't seem to be the cause for these files being created.  I am new to VS and not a programmer, and this is not my project.  I am simply responsible for automating it via the CLI.  Please excuse my ignorance and assist me.

**TL;DR
How do I ensure that devenv does exactly the same thing as the GUI when I run /rebuild?  How do I ensure that Devenv uses the preprocessor Macros that are defined in the project?**

Answer (score 1):

They are different animals probably always have been and the rumor is they aren't in VS2013, but I'll believe that when I see it.

The pre-processor macros do run from both. Check the conditions in your .*proj file that determine if `<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>` matches your expectations of what preprocessor conditions would be.

run your build both in VS and in msbuild with `/v:diag` and look for differences in the the DefineConstants property.  to make VS do that level of logging it is in Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity.